# Create a new list by comparing values in a list and string

Tags: python, string, list

I have elements in a predefined list and a query string.  I would like to check if the `query_str` has any values in the predefined list and if so, append them to a new list as separate elements.

```
predefined_lst = ['hello', 'goodbye', 'see you later']

query_str  = 'hello | are you having a nice day?  see you later |'

new_lst = []
```

I have the syntax to compare the string to the values in the list, but I can't get the values that appear in the string to append to the new list as individual elements in the list.
In the example above, `new_lst` should be `new_lst = ['hello', 'see you later']`.

What I have now just results in True when I print `new_lst`.

```
predefined_lst = ['hello', 'goodbye', 'see you later']
query_str  = 'hello | are you having a nice day?  see you later |'
new_lst = []
match = if any(string in query_str for string in predefined_lst)
new_lst.append(match)
print(new_lst)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you are appending a `True` or `False` value to `new_lst` in your line,

```
match = if any(string in query_str for string in predefined_lst)
```

This is because `if ...` returns the boolean `True` or `False`.

Instead, try this

```
for x in predefined_list:
    if x in query_str:
        new_list.append(x)
```

Or as a list comp,

```
new_lst = [string for string in predefined_lst if string in query_str]
```

Comment: '|' is not a special symbol in his string. It is not a separator.

Comment: Actually, that line with the `if` is a syntax error.

Comment: @kindall Fixed.

Answer (score 6):

You've got lost in the list comprehension:

```
new_lst = [string for string in predefined_lst if string in query_str]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way, using `filter`:

```
>>> predefined_lst = ['hello', 'goodbye', 'see you later']
>>> query_str  = 'hello | are you having a nice day?  see you later |'
>>> 
>>> list(filter(lambda s: s in query_str, predefined_lst))
['hello', 'see you later']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split) to parse out by various delimiters:

```
[i.strip() for i in re.split(r'[?|]',query_str) if i.strip() in predefined_lst]
```

Or:

```
[i for i in re.split(r'(\s+)?[?|](\s+)?',query_str) if i in predefined_lst]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple solution:

```
predefined_lst = ['hello', 'goodbye', 'see you later']
query_str  = 'hello | are you having a nice day?  see you later |'
new_lst = []
for item in predefined_lst:
    if item in query_str:
        new_lst.append(item)
print(new_lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are appending the result of comparison to new_list. What you should be appending is the string itself.

```
predefined_lst = ['hello', 'goodbye', 'see you later']
query_str  = 'hello | are you having a nice day?  see you later |'
new_lst = []
for str in predefined_lst: 
    if(str in query_str):
        new_lst.append(str)
print new_lst
```